# Custom taxonomy - Parent tax title, child tax title & 3 posts - terms ok but can't get the post loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type called "archives" and a custom, hierarchal taxonomy called "types" with parent and child tax terms

I am trying to create an archive page that lists like this

Tax Parent 1

-Child 1

--child post

--child post

--child post

**MORE- link to Parent1.Child 1 archive**

-Child 2

--child post

--child post

--child post

**MORE- link to Parent1.Child 2 archive**

Tax Parent 2

-Child 1

--child post

--child post

--child post

**MORE- link to Parent2.Child 1 archive**

I currently have the Parent and Child terms grouped correctly but I can't seem to get the loop for the child posts to work

http://pastebin.com/EWH3c4Gk

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're most of the way there!

One small point first -- I think it'll read a little easier if you assigned each get_terms call to a variable instead of calling it directly in the foreach loop. I've seen instances where including the function call directly like that can cause issues.

Anyways, with that in mind I believe you'd just need to include this as your missing loop:

```
$childposts = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post_type' => 'archives',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'types',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => $child_term->term_id
        ),
    ),
  )
);

foreach($childposts->posts as $cp):
  echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($cp->ID).'">'.$cp->post_title.' <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>';
endforeach;
```

For more info on the WP_Query class and the tax_query structure, read here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: It doesnt like the line starting with post_type

I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW"
Paste of full updated code here - http://pastebin.com/aCpjrQR2

Comment: D'oh! I'm sorry, I wasn't near a testing machine when I typed that up. I left out the array wrapper. I've updated my code block to what should work!

Comment: Whoops, almost there, thank you.

Now I get 

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object on line 71 
Notice: Undefined property: WP_Tax_Query::$ID on line 71
Notice: Undefined property: WP_Tax_Query::$post_title on line 71

Line 71 is currently   echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink($cp->ID).'">'.$cp->post_title.' <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"

So it doesn't like something about the foreach statement. 

ideas? thank you!!

Comment: Oh dear... sorry for the typo.. Forgot one important piece, the ->posts call in the foreach line. I've updated my code, and actually TESTED it this time. :) Sorry for the mistakes!

Comment: Thank you! I am very grateful. I had a couple of variations close to this but the syntax was wrong so this has been very educational. I am most appreciative!!